# Is there a good way to find proper index?

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking any package or module to find index more fast than my coding.

If there is an numpy array, like

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

So these are a[0]=1, a[1]=2, a[2]=3, a[3]=4, a[4]=5, a[5]=6. In this situation, I'd like to find two index (just before and just after) around 3.5
So, this solution are a[2] and a[3], right?

Well, I took this way

```
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    difference1 = 3.5 - a[i]
    difference2 = 3.5 - a[i + 1]
    if difference1 * difference2 < 0:
        print(i)
```

So I can find a[2]. and i can know a[3] is a little bigger than 3.5 which of all the things i have.
but this is just an example. I deal with more huge data, So there need a lot of time. Is there any tool (module or package) to find more faster in python?

Comment: Why are you tagging with "python-3" when your code is Python 2 (see the `print` statement)?

Comment: oh, i am sorry. this is my fault. i will correct code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution using numpy.  I'm assuming that your array is sorted from your example.

- Add the value that you are looking for to a copy of the array
- Re-sort the new array
- Find the value you are looking for.  The index of the value "to the left" is the index you are looking for.

I mocked up this version, and over a 10M element array the method performed about 10x faster than the original.  I've also not tried to merge together each numpy activity (you could do this in one long line if you want) for clarity.

Specific answer to your example:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
print numpy.where(numpy.sort(numpy.concatenate((a,[3.5])))==3.5)[0][0] - 1
```

Longer example for more explanation:

```
import time
import numpy
a = numpy.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
f = 3.5

#Replacing with a larger range of values to search for timing test
a = numpy.arange(10000000)
f = 500000.5

print "starting new version"
start = time.time()
b = numpy.concatenate((a,[f]))
c = numpy.sort(b)
d = numpy.where(c==f)[0][0] - 1
print d
end = time.time()
print end-start

print "do it in one unreadable line"
start = time.time()
print numpy.where(numpy.sort(numpy.concatenate((a,[f])))==f)[0][0] - 1
end = time.time()
print end-start

print "starting original  version"
start = time.time()
for i in range(len(a) - 1):
    difference1 = f - a[i]
    difference2 = f - a[i + 1]
    if difference1 * difference2 < 0:
        print i

end = time.time()
print end-start
```

EDIT: Put the longer example second so it doesn't look like my suggested solution is 30 lines long!

Comment: Thank you very much. i really want to like this. By the way, i have one more problem. well, i have to find twice. to show you a simple example, there are two function. one is " y = -x**2 + 4" and the other is " y = 0 ". so these plot cross 2 times. it mean when to make plot with python, i have to find twice. but the code you teached me is including sort. i guess, in this case it's difficult to find index. is there any good idea?

Comment: when to cross at x = 2 and x = -2. so i need the indexes around 2 and -2.

Comment: I'm not clear on your second problem - are you trying to use python to solve the polynomial equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "I really want to like this" - is there a problem with the solution?  Just wondering what is missing.

Comment: Actually, i am making the magnetic field around the neutron star. You know, magenet field is not considered inner of neutron star(medial neutron star) and outer light cylinder(it's because the theory of relativity). So i should remove useless indexes.

Comment: that meaning is that your answer is to good way to reduce working hours.

Comment: Any way, i thought about good way to find two point with your idea.

Comment: Glad to hear you found the two point answer.  Do you mind marking this as an "accepted answer"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to work with two consecutive values in a list.
This is a classic problem that you can simplify like this:

```
for prev_a, next_a in zip(a[:-1], a[1:]):
    difference1 = 3.5 - prev_a
    difference2 = 3.5 - next_a
    if difference1 * difference2 < 0:
        print("diffrence found")
```

If you really need the index, you can use `enumerate`:

```
for index, (prev_a, next_a) in enumerate(zip(a[:-1], a[1:])):
    difference1 = 3.5 - prev_a
    difference2 = 3.5 - next_a
    if difference1 * difference2 < 0:
        print index
```

If you want to be faster, you can calculate the products first, then compare:

```
diff_list = [3.5 - value for value in a]
for index, (prev_diff, next_diff) in enumerate(zip(diff_list[:-1], diff_list[1:])):
    if prev_diff * next_diff < 0:
        print(index)
```